# How can I cover a function with callback function using jasmine unit test case

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular10, angular14

I am working with Angular, Jasmine and Karma.
Want to cover unit test case for the following scenario

```
public obj: ClassA = new ClassA();
this.obj.forEachFeatureAtPixel(param, async (abc: any) => {
});
```

Here callback function not getting called. How can I cover this?